# C taking lines of file and putting them to separate indexes of an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to take lines of a file and put them to a unique index of an array of strings as such:

```
char *fileString[newline_count];
        rewind(makeFile);
        int i;
        int i2 = 0;
        int i3 = 0;
        char temp[500];
        for(i = 0; i < string_size; i++){
            temp[i3] = fgetc(makeFile);
            if(temp[i3] == '\n'){
                temp[i3] = '\0';
                fileString[i2] = temp;
                i2++;
                i3 = 0;
            }else{
                i3++;
            }   
        }

        for(i = 0; i < newline_count; i++){
            printf("%s %c", fileString[i], '\n');
        }
```

The last for loop just prints out the contects of fileString which is the array of strings. i is an index for the first for loop, i2 is an index for the fileString, and i3 is an index for the temp char which will be stored into fileString once the contents of a line are put into temp.
I'm wondering why the contents of fileString are
the last line over and over again. The last for loop just prints out the last line of the file for the amount of lines there are within the file. I'm completely lost, and very very tired so I am seeking help here. I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration the buffer `temp` is assigned to each position in `fileString`.  In other words, all entries in the array point to the same buffer (which contains the last line read at the end).

A "quick" fix would be to change that line to:

```
fileString[i2] = strdup(temp);
```

If you do this, you need to free each entry to avoid a leak.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `temp` to every index of `fileString`; this causes every element of `fileString` to point to the same thing – first element of the `temp` array. Since you keep overwriting the contents of `temp` with each new line, it ends up only containing the last line when you are done reading the file.

You need to copy the contents of `temp` somewhere else (and unique) to keep them, and point `fileString` to that copy, not to your temporary `temp` array. For example, `malloc` new memory of sufficient length after reading each line and `strcpy` the line from `temp` to that location (which you must then `free` once you are done with it). A quick way is to use `strdup` which does essentially the same as the `malloc` and `strcpy` combined, but is a non-standard function (so, for practice if nothing else, implement your own `strdup`).

Answer (score 1):

Reading in each individual character and putting them into a string is unnecessary. Use fgets(). I would allocate memory for each line, get the data, and then store a pointer to that allocated data in some data structure.

For example,

```
  // Allocate an array pointers, using 1000 as our initial size.
  int lineReferencesSize = 1000;
  char **lineReferences = (char **) malloc (sizeof(char *) * lineReferencesSize);
  char buf[100];

  int i = 0;
  while(fgets(buf, 100, fin)) {
    lineReferences[i] = strdup(buf);
    i++;
  }
```

Remember to free() when you're done.

Now, lineReferences is a fixed size array of pointers that can store 1000 char * pointers. For serious purposes, I would consider a data structure that did not have an arbitrary fixed size. You could do this by making lineReferences a dynamic array, resizing it when you hit your limit, realloc()ing to double the amount, and going forward. There are some interesting edge cases to consider (read the man page on realloc).

You can alternatively write it like this as well:

```
  // Allocate an array pointers, using 1000 as our initial size.
  char *lineReferences[1000];
  char buf[100];

  int i = 0;
  while(fgets(buf, 100, fin)) {
    lineReferences[i] = strdup(buf);
    i++;
  }
```

But it's important to understand what's going on with the other form.